# How to generate links to the android Classes' reference in javadoc?

Tags: android, javadoc

When I generate javadoc for my Android project in Eclipse, there are lots of warnings like

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TextView
```

and

```
warning - Tag @see: reference not found: android.app.Dialog
```

I also tried

```
-link http://developer.android.com/reference/
-link http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/
```

in `Extra javadoc options (path names with white spaces must be enclosed in quotes)` tab in `Configure Javadoc Arguments` (3rd dialog of eclipse->project->Generate Javadoc).

But only `-link http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/` is working i.e for String class 
link `http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true` is generated. but for `android.app.Dialog` , no link is generated.

**Edit**

I also tried selecting `android.jar` in `Select referenced archives and projects to which links should be generated`
tab in `Configure Javadoc arguments for standard doclet` (2nd dialog of eclipse->project->Generate Javadoc),
but this creates local links to docs in local android-sdk directory, NOT the online Android references like it does for Java APIs.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Javadoc relies on a file called `package-list` to determine what Java packages are documented below a given directory. For some reason, such a file is **missing** for http://d.android.com/reference/, therefore the "naive" approach with

```
-link http://d.android.com/reference/
```

doesn't work – you get a warning that the package-list could not be retrieved and no links are generated into your docs. (Note: The checkboxes in that 2nd eclipse dialog just assemble `-link` parameters for you, so that doesn't really make any difference)

However, Javadoc offers the `-linkoffline` parameter to be able to adjust for precisely **this** situation: You want to link to some other Javadoc documentation online, but you cannot access it at the time of generating your own docs. Here's how it works: While `-link` takes only one parameter (the URL of the JavaDoc docs you want to link to), `-linkoffline` takes a second one. That one is the location of the `package-list` file!

So, to link to the online Android reference documentation, you should **not** select any checkboxes in the 2nd eclipse dialog, but instead add

```
-linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference file:/C:/pathtoyour/android-sdk-windows/docs/reference
```

in the *Extra Javadoc options* in the 3rd dialog. That way you use the `package-list` of your locally installed Android docs, but the links in your generated Javadoc will still point to the online version anyway.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Henning, It worked !! I really had spent a lot of time to solve this but not succeeded. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't seem to get the filepath in the second argument correct on Mac OS X.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I wasn't able to get it to work for me.  Specifically, I'm using Eclipse on Windows.  My javadoc includes references like "{@link android.widget.Toast}".  When I choose "Generate Javadoc...", I do not check anything on the second screen, and I include the extra Javadoc option `-linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference file:"\C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\docs\"`.  Javadoc is generated without error, but it includes `android.widget.Toast` where I expected a link.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: **1.** You need the path to the `reference` directory _below_ the `docs` directory. **2.** Don't use path names with parentheses on Windows -- it breaks all the time (especially with Java). **3.** Use forward slashes (also with Java). **4.** The quotation marks probably need to include the `file:` as well, as it's part of the URI. **Summary:** Move (or symlink) your Android SDK to `C:\Android`, then use `-linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference "file:/C:/Android/android-sdk-windows/docs/reference"`

Comment: Should it not be `file://C:/...`?

Comment: It worked not for me. I m using Eclipse on Windows too, and I have added 
      `-linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference file:/D:/Programme/Android/android-sdk/docs/reference`
(package-list file is there).
I did not check anything else, but I get lots of 'error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;' errors

Any suggestions whats the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

By now (August 2020), Google has published a `package-list` on its Android developer documentation. Hence, simply linking to https://developer.android.com/reference/ or https://d.android.com/reference/ will work (just tried this with success).

Minor glitch: if you open the generated Javadoc and try to follow a link to an Android class (or one of the standard Java classes, which will also link to the Android documentation) and you are in frame mode, your browser might refuse to follow the link, as the Android site does not allow embedding in another page. Firefox then gives you the alternative of opening the target document in a new tab.

Comment: If you want AndroidX in the same way, you can also add `-linkoffline https://developer.android.com/reference/ https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/`

Comment: http:// doesn't work with no log output, https:// works

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of trial and error (And plenty of suggestions gleaned from multiple web searches), I was able to get this working with a specific ANT script, which can be run in Eclipse by "Run As -> Ant Build".

I saved this file, "javadoc.xml", in the directory of my project, in parallel with the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Here is the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="doc" name="api docs">
<target name="doc" description="my docs">
<javadoc destdir="docs" doctitle="Testing the Title" verbose="on" 
    use="true" 
    classpath="C:\Android\android-sdk_r04-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-2.1\android.jar;.\libs\admob-sdk-android.jar"
    sourcepath="gen;src"
    linkoffline="http://d.android.com/reference C:\Android\android-sdk_r04-windows\android-sdk-windows\docs\reference"
    stylesheetfile="C:\Android\android-sdk_r04-windows\android-sdk-windows\docs\assets\android-developer-docs.css"
    >
</javadoc>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I followed to top answer here, I found I could only get it to work if I exported an ant build file (javadoc.xml), and manually added the android.jar file to the classpath. My javadoc.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="javadoc">
    <target name="javadoc">
        <javadoc access="private" additionalparam=" -linkoffline http://developer.android.com/reference file:/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/docs/reference" author="true" classpath=".:/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/platforms/android-8/android.jar" destdir="doc" nodeprecated="false" nodeprecatedlist="false" noindex="false" nonavbar="false" notree="false" packagenames="com.example.mypackagename" source="1.5" sourcepath="gen:src" splitindex="true" use="true" version="true"/>
   </target>
</project>
```

I could then generate the document using `ant -f javadoc.xml`. I couldn't figure out a way to do it properly from the Eclipse GUI, as even selecting the correct referenced archive did not cause Eclipse to add android.jar to the classpath.

Comment: If you use Eclipse Indigo, in the 4th frame of exporting Javadoc, at box _Extra Javadoc options_, you can paste your value of attribute `additionalparam` into there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Henning

Here is what I needed in ant build.xml file:

```
<link offline="true" href="http://d.android.com/reference" packagelistLoc="${android.home}/docs/reference"/>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I used this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193647/624109

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with the path to the SDK you can manually create a `package-list` file (or copy the one under `$ANDROID_HOME/docs/reference/package-list`) to your project.

To use a relative path you shouldn't use the `file:/` prefix. If you put the file in `sub-directory/package-list` the argument would be `-linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference sub-directory`

Answer (score 0):

For those of us daring enough to have switched over to the ever-evolving Android Studio & Gradle, one of the things that actually works and makes things a little easier is referring to a package-list location either locally or on the web.  For example, the following code from [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23604253/4307281) generates javadoc files:

```
task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    title = "Documentation for Android $android.defaultConfig.versionName b$android.defaultConfig.versionCode"
    destinationDir = new File("${project.getProjectDir()}/doc/compiled/", variant.baseName)
    source = variant.javaCompile.source
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)

    description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."

    options.memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PRIVATE
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.links("http://developer.android.com/reference/reference/");
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
}
```

But this resulted in a warning during the build because the package-list isn't available anymore (if it ever was) at

```
options.links("http://developer.android.com/reference/reference/");
```

At first I thought maybe the redundant reference/reference was the issue, but the package-list was also unavailable at

```
options.links("http://developer.android.com/reference/");
```

So, after reading the discussion on this thread, that one line can be changed to refer to the local reference directory within the SDK:

```
options.links("c:\\path-to-sdk-directory\\docs\\reference");
```

It finds the package-list locally and doesn't display the warning message anymore.