# Javadoc on Android (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, javadoc

I am trying to generate Javadoc html pages for my Android project in Eclipse. I have tried using the `-linkoffline` argument, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818204/how-to-generate-links-to-the-android-classes-reference-in-javadoc), as well as using the `-classpath` argument pointing to my android.jar file. Neither of these worked, as I still get `package android.app does not exist` (and other) warnings. I have also tried running the javadoc tool from the command line, rather than using Eclipse.

Ideally I would like to have my own generated pages for my classes, with all android.* and java.* classes linking to the online pages. I am using Mac OS 10.6 with Java version 1.6.0_20.

Answer (score 3):

While trying to resolve a similar issue myself, the two main points I've found have been:

- To include the *android.jar* file you're linking to within the classpath attribute of the *javadoc* Ant task. That means something like the following:

  ```
  <javadoc ... 
    classpath="some/local/library.jar;
      C:/Android/platforms/android-8/android.jar;
      D:/another/library.jar" ... >
  ```
- To add a *link* subitem under javadoc task in order to match the online Android Reference URL with a local copy of Android Reference *package-list*. That means something like the following:

  ```
  <javadoc ...>
     <link offline="true" 
       href="http://developer.android.com/reference/" 
       packagelistloc="C:/Android/docs/reference" />
  </javadoc>
  ```

This was enough for me in order to show Android links within my project Javadoc.

Comment: That worked for me but I still have "package com.mypackage.R does not exist" warning.

Comment: Sorry not to be helpful. I don't have that environment set up at the moment.

Comment: @superjos can you tell me please, where do I have to write those lines

Comment: @5er usually you have a `build.xml` file for your project, that is an Ant Build file, used to build/compile/package the project source files from the command line (and also from Eclipse UI, if needed).
In that file you create a *target* dedicated to doc generation, and within that a Javadoc *task* to perform the actual operation. You can see an example in @junkdog answer on this page

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an ant script for the javadocs? Name it **javadoc.xml** or something other than **build.xml** - else eclipse will pick it up as the default build script. Run the ant script either from inside eclipse (`RMB on file | Run As | Ant Build`), or from the console: `ant -f <file-name.xml>`.

Mine looks something similar to this:

```
<project basedir="." default="doc" name="metagloss api docs">

    <property 
        name="android-sdk-docs"
        value="/home/blackrax/opt/dev/android-sdk-linux_86/docs/reference"/>

    <target name="doc" description="api docs - no piwik" depends="clean, delombok">
        <javadoc destdir="docs">
            <link offline="true"
                  href="http://d.android.com/reference"
                  packagelistLoc="${android-sdk-docs}" />
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java" />
        </javadoc>
    </target>

    <!-- more implementation, any remaining targets -->
</project>
```

Comment: Did that solve the `package android.app does not exist` problems?