# Generate JavaDocs with Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc, android-gradle-plugin

How can I generate JavaDocs for an Android project using the new Gradle build system?

Here is what I have come up with but it doesn't work.

```
task generateJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    ext.cp = android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.classpath.files
    }
    classpath = files(ext.cp) 
}
```

The main problem is that I do not get the appropriate android.jar on the classpath so some of the links in the JavaDocs are not resolved. I have to find a way to get all the necessary jars on the classpath.

Another problem with the approach I took is it collects the classpaths for all the build variants, rather than selecting one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle, Javadoc and Android documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297562/gradle-javadoc-and-android-documentation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution I ended up settling on is as follows:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    task("generate${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = "${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
    }

}
```

Xavier Ducrohet confirmed this is the way to do it (with caveats) on the adt-dev group, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/javadoc/adt-dev/seRizEn8ICA/bafEvUl6mzsJ.

Comment: If you get "javaCompile" is deprecated in latest version of android studio, change to "javaCompiler"

Comment: If you get 'variant.getJavaCompiler()' is deprecated, use `variant.javaCompileProvider.get().source` and `variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath`

Comment: [note] javadoc was generated but was empty. Final solution I used was
`source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
classpath += variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath`

Comment: @istrocode THANK YOU. I was struggling to replace my deprecated calls but despite looking at several guides, there was no clear indication that you should use `TaskProvider.get()`. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 42):

For Android gradle plugin 1.1.2+ (com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2+)

*libraryVariants* - does not work anymore

**use:**

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    failOnError false
}
```

**destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")** - locate javadocs at root of project directory (in this way jenkins javadoc plugin could find it and show in special Document panel)

**failOnError false** - for suppress warnings that can cause fail build on jenkins

Comment: +1 Absolute genius!!! Every approach I have seen (examples are all over this SO q) for creating javadocs for aars uses the `.all` approach which is long-winded and cant be called from other consuming tasks. This approach is so much cleaner and usable.

Comment: Gradle says "Cannot add task ':mossosdesign:javadoc' as a task with that name already exists."

Answer (score 24):

Gradle 1.11 - Gradle Plugin **0.10.0**

**Replace `android.plugin.sdkDirectory` by `android.sdkDirectory`**

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    task("generate${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
        options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/");
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
    }
}
```

Comment: Works, though I would use `"generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc"` for a slightly better formatted task name (e.g., `generateReleaseJavadoc` versus `generatereleaseJavadoc`).

Comment: I had to use `options.linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference");` instead of `options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/");`. Otherwise it gave a warning and wouldn't link to the Android documentation. Besides this it seems to work great!

Comment: Better than building your own path to the android jar with `ext.androidJar` would be to simply use `android.bootClasspath`. `classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(android.bootClasspath)`

Answer (score 9):

With android gradle tools 1.10.+ getting the android SDK dir is different than before. You have to change the following:

```
android.sdkDirectory
```

instead of

```
android.plugin.sdkDirectory
```

This is the complete solution to the problem:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        title = "Documentation for Android $android.defaultConfig.versionName b$android.defaultConfig.versionCode"
        destinationDir = new File("${project.getProjectDir()}/doc/compiled/", variant.baseName)
        source = variant.javaCompile.source

        ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)

        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."

        options.memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PRIVATE
        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
        options.links("http://developer.android.com/reference/");
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `android.sdkDirectory` instead of `android.plugin.sdkDirectory` (https://plus.google.com/114432517923423045208/posts/NphSRvqAo6m)

Comment: I had to leave out the exclude of the R.java files otherwise I did get a lot of errors, but this was the solution that worked for me too.

Comment: Thanks, just note it must be  `options.links("https://developer.android.com/reference/")` and not `options.links("https://developer.android.com/reference/reference")`

Answer (score 8):

The android jars seem to be in the property `android.plugin.runtimeJarList`. It's not documented anywhere though, so it might break at anytime.

I've refined your solution to work across build variants:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.name
    task "javadoc$name"(type: Javadoc) {
        description = "Generates javadoc for build $name"
        destinationDir = new File(destinationDir, variant.baseName)
        source = files(variant.javaCompile.source)
        classpath = files(android.plugin.runtimeJarList, variant.javaCompile.classpath)
        exclude '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html'
    }
}
```

It generally doesn't make sense to do a javadoc on just the main branch since you might rely on some things from the product flavors. Even debug vs release could have some differences. You could of course, just pick a default variant to use. So you could do something like,

```
task javadoc(dependsOn: javadocDebug)
```

Comment: Got error `Could not find property 'applicationVariants'` as of AS 0.2.9 tips?

Comment: Oh figured it out, if you are building a library project, you need to use `android.libraryVariants` as the OP did instead.

Comment: After getting your solution to compile, no tasks was added. Seems the variants list are empty as I've confirmed in by adding [this debug task](https://gist.github.com/chakrit/6590917). Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to work for me. I changed applicationVariants to libraryVariants and it adds a javadocDebug task for me. Maybe you should update the android plugin and/or gradle?

Comment: R.java files can be excluded with the following line in the task:
`exclude '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html'`

Comment: i would include `task(..., dependsOn: "assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}")` else javadoc may fail if the version is not uptodate

Answer (score 4):

Here is a updated version that used to work in 2014:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("debug")) {
        return; // Skip debug builds.
    }
    task("javadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = files(plugins.findPlugin("com.android.library").getBootClasspath())
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + ext.androidJar
        exclude '**/internal/**'
        failOnError false
    }

    task("bundleJavadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: Jar) {
        description "Bundles Javadoc into zip for $variant.name."
        classifier = "javadoc"
        from tasks["javadoc${variant.name.capitalize()}"]
    }
}
```

Comment: `plugins.findPlugin("com.android.library").getBootClasspath()` failed for me with Gradle 2.3, Gradle Android Plugin 1.2.3. But it worked when I removed the whole ext.androidJar line (and the line following it that uses it).

Answer (score 3):

I made an open source plugin for that. [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-javadoc-plugin)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.vanniktech:gradle-android-javadoc-plugin:0.2.1"
    }
}
```

Add this line into your **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.vanniktech.android.javadoc"
```

Then just execute one of the following:

```
./gradlew generateDebugJavadoc
./gradlew generateReleaseJavadoc
```

The java documentation can be found in `module/javaDoc/`

Answer (score 2):

I found that this solution works on Gradle plugin 1.3.1 if you have different product flavors.

This will create Gradle tasks to generate Javadoc for each product flavor and build type. For instance, if the module name is `app` and you have a `production` and `dev` product flavor and `debug` and `release` build types, you'll have the following Gradle tasks:

- :app:generateDevDebugJavadoc
- :app:generateDevReleaseJavadoc
- :app:generateProductionDebugJavadoc
- :app:generateProductionReleaseJavadoc

**`app/build.gradle`**

```
android {

    // ...

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // create tasks to generate Javadocs
        task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
            source = variant.javaCompile.source
            classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))

            // choose the destination that works best for you here
            // I chose this particular directory because Jenkins pulls reports 
            // from this directory already if you need to have the output 
            // folder be parameterized for the build variant, use
            // "build/outputs/docs/javadoc-${variant.name}/" instead and it'll 
            // be in `javadoc-productionRelease` for example
            destinationDir = file("build/outputs/docs/javadoc/")

            // the name that will appear in the docs
            title = rootProject.name

            // you will probably get errors from using the @annotations and 
            // the support library, so just turn off failing for errors
            failOnError false    
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    if(variant.name.equals('release'))
        task("generateJavadoc", type: Javadoc) {
            description "Generate Javadoc"
            source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
//            println '=== source ==='
//            source.collect { relativePath(it) }.sort().each { println it }
            ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
            classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
//            println '=== classpath ==='
//            classpath.collect { relativePath(it) }.sort().each { println it }
        }
}
```

Use:

gradle generateJavadoc