# Gradle, Javadoc and Android documentation

Tags: android, javadoc, android-gradle-plugin

I'm now using Gradle for all my projects, and even for javadoc generation.

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    task("generate${variant.name}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        title = "$name $version API"
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        ext.androidJar = "${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        ext.googlePlayServicesJar = "${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files, ext.androidJar, ext.googlePlayServicesJar)
        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
        options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/");
        //options.linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference");
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
    }

}
```

With that code I got everything working, except one thing: regular Android API objects like Activity, Bitmap etc.
Java's links are working fine.

The final generated documentation does not **link** to http://d.android.com/reference.
I tried both options.links() and `options.linksOffline()` without success.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @ejb, the problem was that you cannot provide multiple `options.links()` at the same time.
So I used both `options.links()` for Java's documentation and `options.linksOffline()` for Android's documentation:

```
options {
    links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.plugin.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference");
    //stylesheetFile = new File(projectDir, "stylesheet.css");
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to successfully link to http://d.android.com/reference using the following snippet *which is functionally exactly what you have* (as far as I can tell).

```
 android.libraryVariants.all { variant -> 
   task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
     // title = ''
     // description = ''
     source = variant.javaCompile.source 
     classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files, project.android.getBootClasspath()) 
     options { 
       links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/" 
       linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference","${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference" 
     } 
     exclude '**/BuildConfig.java' 
     exclude '**/R.java' 
   } 
 }
```

So there is something else amiss here.

You have to build the javadoc offline, as it doesn't seem the `package-list` is available on the path of the web service.  Maybe double check that you actually have the docs loaded locally, and make sure there is a `package-list` in the `/[android-sdk]/docs/reference` directory.

If you still can't figure it out, perhaps you could post output.

Another thing you might check is the `./build/tmp/[taskname]/javadoc.options`, the `head` of said file should show the appropriate options carefully set.  Things to check for would include the proper inclusion of the android.jar in the -classpath and the presence of linksOffline with expected arguments: [`-linksoffline extDocURL packageListLoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#linkoffline)

`javadoc.options` should have both options with only the respective arguments:

```
-linksoffline 'http://d.android.come/reference' '[sdkDir]/docs/reference'
-links 'http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/'
```

**EDIT**: `android.getBootClasspath()` is nicer, thanks to P-chan.

Comment: `package-list` is present, `[android-sdk]/docs/reference` is present, `build/tmp/generatereleaseJavadoc/javadoc.options` indeed contains `-link 'http://d.android.com/reference/'` etc. I also tried your exact Gradle task... nothing changes :(

Comment: Using this task works for me. I only had to change `android.plugin.sdkDirectory` to `android.sdkDirectory`.

Comment: @shkschneider - the javadoc.options should contain the `-linksoffline http://d.android.com/reference [sdkdir]/docs/reference`, not just `-links http://d.android.com/reference`?

Comment: @ejb yes, it has both in `javadoc.options` generated file

Comment: @shkschneider can you post `head javadoc.options` on pastebin or as a gist? `http://d.android.com/reference` shouldn't be included in the `-links` option. `-links` should just have the Oracle javadoc link...

Comment: @ejb I was getting ready to post you my different configurations, turns I got the solution thx to you. See my question's edit.

Comment: Why link to Oracle's site for the java docs? Java is included in Android.

Comment: android.getBootClasspath() can be used to get the android.jar's location too, which is simpler. Then you'll do: 
classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files, project.android.getBootClasspath())

Comment: @P-chan `android.getBootClasspath()` is indeed nicer. Also, do not forget to use double-quotes and not single-quotes when using variable inside strings.

Comment: does not work Could not find property 'libraryVariants' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@491cafec.

Comment: Neither -links or -lingsoffline works for me. I get `javadoc: error - invalid flag: -linkoffline`.

Comment: @petrakeas - I noticed in your comment that you misspelled _lingsoffline_ - and again in your snippet _linkoffline_.  You may want to double check you used: `linksOffline`(camel caps).

Comment: @ejb Sorry for that! I typed it correctly on my gradle configuration. It seems that the doclet I am using (doclava) does not support this flag. I have left a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422458/create-external-link-in-javadoc-using-gradle-in-android-studio

Answer (score 15):

For **Android Gradle plugin 1.1.2+** (com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.+)

*libraryVariants* - does not work anymore

**use:**

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    failOnError false
}
```

*destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")* - locate javadocs at root of project directory (in this way jenkins javadoc plugin could find it and show in special Document panel)

*failOnError false* - for suppress warnings that can cause fail build on jenkins

---

### Alternative for Gradle JavaDocs

***Doxygen*** - cross reference documentation tool.

could be run from UI or terminal: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/doxygen_usage.html

---

Generating javadoc available throw java tool: '**javadoc**'

run from command line:

```
javadoc -d docs -sourcepath app/src/main/java -subpackages com
```

*docs* - destination folder

Comment: `libraryVariants` still work for me as of Gradle 1.1.0 AND your code only works for Gradle 1.1.2+ because of http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152811 but thanks for the update

Comment: This works fine for me. Although I added the extra line `classpath += configurations.compile` before the line which sets the classpath. Without this it would not find the methods from the JAR libraries I had in my project.