# Create external link in Javadoc using Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I have created a Gradle task that generates a javadoc using Doclava:

My code (the arguments of some of my methods) references classes defined in Android. When Javadoc is built, these references link correctly to the Android online reference. However, when I use the **`@ling` tag** to link to Android references, it does not work and I get something like:

```
configurations {
    jaxDoclet
    classpaths
}

dependencies {

    // For Doclava JavaDoc
    jaxDoclet("com.google.doclava:doclava:1.0.6")
    classpaths files('build/intermediates/classes/debug')
    classpaths project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.allJava
    source += fileTree("build/generated/source/r/debug")
    title = null
    options {
        docletpath = configurations.jaxDoclet.files.asType(List)
        doclet "com.google.doclava.Doclava"
        bootClasspath new File(System.getenv('JAVA_HOME') + "/jre/lib/rt.jar")
        classpath += configurations.classpaths.files.asType(List)
        addStringOption "public"
        addStringOption "federate android", "http://d.android.com/reference"
        addStringOption "federationxml android", "http://doclava.googlecode.com/svn/static/api/android-10.xml"
    }
}
```

> warning 101: Unresolved link/see tag "Runnable" in com....

In [similar questions in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297562/gradle-javadoc-and-android-documentation), it was advised to use `-link` and `-linkoffline` flags. However, when I do that I get:

```
javadoc: error - invalid flag: -linkoffline
```

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and Gradle 2.11.

***Update***
It seems that Doclava may not support `-link` and `-linksoffline` according to [these](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doclava/issues/44) [tickets](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doclava/issues/2). If I use the default doclet, links work correctly.