# How do I make sure that Classes from my dependencies are included in javadoc when building an Android library with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm building an Android library with gradle, but getting loads of errors similar to this:

```
/Users/scott/dev/libs/mysqlitedatabase-android/mysqlitedatabase-android-
library/src/main/java/com/mypackage/android/sub/MyDatabaseSync.java:
14: error: package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
                            ^
```

Here is the gradle task I use to generate the javadoc:

```
task generateJavadoc (type: Javadoc) {
    def variant = android.libraryVariants.release
    title = "$project.name $version API"
    description "Generates Javadoc for $project.name."
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath += project.files(source) + files(variant.processJavaResources.destinationDir)
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/");
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
}
```

I've built numerous libraries before, but with older gradle versions. I am using gradle 1.12 on this occasion.

Comment: Just to be clear. This is error while building library or while generating javadoc?

Comment: The project builds fine. The `generateJavadoc` task is used when publishing, but I also get the error if I call the task individually.

Comment: I think you forgot to add `files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files)` to classpath. Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033878/generate-javadocs-with-android-gradle-plugin

Comment: Still the same I'm afraid :(