# Why JavaDoc generate gradle task doesn't work with Android Plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to generate JavaDoc's automatically every time I build the project. According to [this StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033878/generate-javadocs-with-android-gradle-plugin), I've got this quite simple gradle code:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    title = "Documentation for Android $android.defaultConfig.versionName b$android.defaultConfig.versionCode"
    destinationDir = new File("${project.getProjectDir().parent}/docs", variant.baseName)
    source = variant.javaCompile.source

    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)

    description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."

    options.memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PRIVATE
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.links("http://developer.android.com/reference/reference/");
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
}
```

}
It shows me text in console (println's) but doesn't generate JavaDocs. It only does if I write "gradle generateDebugJavaDoc". And it does perfectly. The question is - how to set it so that gradle would auto-generate JavaDocs everytime I build the project?? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

something like `project.task("assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}").dependsOn(myTask)`