# Javadoc generation "error package does not exist" in multi module project

Tags: android, javadoc, gradle-dependencies

I need to upload my libraries(multi-module project) into sonatype repository through Bintray. So that I need to generate the Javadoc individually for each module.

First I faced the problems in these similar questions

[Android Studio Javadoc: Cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571371/android-studio-javadoc-cannot-find-symbol)

[Gradle Javadoc fails with “error: package … does not exist”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943231/gradle-javadoc-fails-with-error-package-does-not-exist)

From the solution in the first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572606/5134215), I can resolve the classes that I have used from third party libraries(retrofit2, gson)  and `@NonNull` annotations errors.

But in my case one of my modules(`Lib2`) depends on another module(`Lib1`).

When generating the Javadoc for `Lib2` module, its warning `package does not exist` & `cannot find symbol` for the classes of another module(`Lib1`).

And both modules reports `package does not exist` error for android support & design libraries.

And Every `import <packagename>.R;` reports `cannot find symbol`

My Javadoc generating task

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
      source = android.sourceSets.main.java.source
      classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
      ext.androidJar ="${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
      classpath += files(ext.androidJar)
      project.android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        classpath += files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files)
      }
}
```

dependencies in Lib1 `build.gradle`

```
compile rootProject.appcompat
compile rootProject.design
compile rootProject.retrofit2
compile rootProject.support
compile rootProject.gsonConverter
compile rootProject.httpLogInterceptor
compile rootProject.universalImageLoader
```

dependencies in Lib2 `build.gradle`

```
compile project(':core')
compile rootProject.appcompat
compile rootProject.design
compile rootProject.retrofit2
compile rootProject.support
compile rootProject.cardview
```

I have tried

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

My entire `gradle-mvn-push.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
// Declaring variables

afterEvaluate {  project ->
  bintray {
    user = bin_user
    key = bin_key
    configurations = ['archives']
    publish = true
    dryRun = false
    pkg {
      repo = REPO
      name = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
      userOrg = USER_ORG
      desc = POM_DESCRIPTION
      websiteUrl = POM_URL
      vcsUrl = GIT_URL
      licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
      version {
        name = VERSION_NAME
        vcsTag = VERSION_NAME
        gpg {
          sign = true
          try {
            passphrase = PASS_PHRASE
          } catch (Exception ignored) {
            println 'Failed to find credentials. GPG sign disabled'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('com.android.application') ||
          project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('com.android.library')) {
    task install(type: Upload, dependsOn: assemble) {
      repositories.mavenInstaller {
        configuration = configurations.archives

        pom.groupId = GROUP
        pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
        pom.version = VERSION_NAME

        pom.project {
          name POM_NAME
          packaging POM_PACKAGING
          description POM_DESCRIPTION
          url POM_URL

          scm {
            url POM_SCM_URL
            connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
            developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
          }

          licenses {
            license {
              name POM_LICENCE_NAME
              url POM_LICENCE_URL
              distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
            }
          }

          developers {
            developer {
              id pom_developer_id
              name pom_developer_name
            }
          }

        }

        pom.withXml {
          def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

          //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
          configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
      source = android.sourceSets.main.java.source
      classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
      ext.androidJar ="${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
      classpath += files(ext.androidJar)
      project.android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        classpath += files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files)
      }
    }

    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
      classifier = 'javadoc'
      from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
      classifier = 'sources'
      from android.sourceSets.main.java.source
    }


  } else {
    install {
      repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.groupId = GROUP
        pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
        pom.version = VERSION_NAME

        pom.project {
          name POM_NAME
          packaging POM_PACKAGING
          description POM_DESCRIPTION
          url POM_URL

          scm {
            url POM_SCM_URL
            connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
            developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
          }

          licenses {
            license {
              name POM_LICENCE_NAME
              url POM_LICENCE_URL
              distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
            }
          }

          developers {
            developer {
              id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
              name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
      classifier = 'sources'
      from sourceSets.main.allSource
    }

    task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:javadoc) {
      classifier = 'javadoc'
      from javadoc.destinationDir
    }
  }

  if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
    allprojects {
      tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
      }
    }
  }

  artifacts {
    if (project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('com.android.application') ||
            project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('com.android.library')) {
      archives androidSourcesJar
      archives androidJavadocsJar
    } else {
      archives sourcesJar
      archives javadocJar
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got solved the issue using below snippet

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc, dependsOn: 'assembleRelease') {
  classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
  android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name == 'release') {
      owner.classpath += variant.javaCompile.classpath
    }
  }
  source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  exclude '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html', '**/index.html'
}
```

But still `import <packagename>.R;` reports `cannot find symbol`.

References:

[Adventures with Javadocs, part 2
(Introducing Android Framework Classes)](http://www.stkent.com/2016/02/05/adventures-with-javadocs-part-2.html#comment-3045502173)

[Adventures with Javadocs, part 3 (Introducing Classes From Third Party Dependencies)](http://www.stkent.com/2016/06/10/adventures-with-javadocs-part-3.html)

Comment: Instead of excluding `'**/R.html'`, you need to exclude `'**/R.java'`, since `exclude` excludes files from the source folder to be processed, not the output.

Comment: For those getting warning `JavaCompile() is obsolete` with the code above, just replace `variant.javaCompile.classpath` by `variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath`