# How do I set links to external AndroidX reference in gradle javadoc tasks?

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc, androidx

Is there a clean way of linking androidx references in my javadoc output (which is generated by gradle javadoc task)?
I am using the below task to generate references for my project. It correctly links java, android, and support library references to the generated otuput.

```
task myJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
  ..
  options {
    ..
    links("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/")
  }
}

afterEvaluate {
  myJavadoc.options.linksOffline("https://developer.android.com/reference", "${project.android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483586/steve) in comment of [How to generate links to the android Classes' reference in javadoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818204/how-to-generate-links-to-the-android-classes-reference-in-javadoc)

```
options.linksOffline('https://d.android.com/reference/', 'https://d.android.com/reference/androidx/')
```

will do the job

Comment: This is what worked for me at the time of writing this comment.